# How to pass data to PopupMenuButton widget's onSelected method?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to delete my Cards via PopupMenuButton.

[image: Day Cards]

But I can't pass any info about current card to its `onSelected` method, it takes `String` and returns `void`.

```
onSelected: (String value) { print('Selected: $value'); },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call another function from there and pass your value -

```
onSelected: (Choice choice) {
          callMethod('some data I am passing');
        },
```

and then call your method like this-

```
callMethod(String data) {
print(data);}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and your help but I just figured it out that my problem was related to 'State Management' rather than popupmenu even though I thought that I can solve it by getting the index of current DayCard.

I have a list of DayCard widgets in my AddDaysPage widget. I wanted to delete entries from that list, but since there is no bidirectional data flow in flutter, I can't notify my parent widget(AddDaysPage) with deleted DayCard widgets. So my problem is related to state management and I have to find solutions about it.

Comment: oh ok. Read about 'InheritedWidget' then.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the same issue still,

```
   In PopupMenuItem you have to specify the value parameter so when a popup item  
    is clicked it sends the corresponding value to onSelected method 

    PopupMenuItem(
    value: value,
    child: Text(value));
    }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
          itemBuilder: (context) => [
            PopupMenuItem(
              child: Text("Edit"),
              value: "edit",
            ),
            PopupMenuItem(
              child: Text("Delete"),
              value: "del",
            )
          ],
          onSelected: (String val) {
            print(val);               
          },
        )
```